# obj-c's class custom initializer doesn't show up in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I just knew swift and I don't have experience with objective-c. Here is an objective-c class that i want to use in my swift code
WebSocket.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class HTTPMessage;
@class GCDAsyncSocket;
#define WebSocketDidDieNotification  @"WebSocketDidDie"
@interface WebSocket : NSObject
{
    dispatch_queue_t websocketQueue;
    HTTPMessage *request;
    GCDAsyncSocket *asyncSocket;
    NSData *term;
    BOOL isStarted;
    BOOL isOpen;
    BOOL isVersion76;
    id __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}
+ (BOOL)isWebSocketRequest:(HTTPMessage *)request;
- (id)initWithRequest:(HTTPMessage *)request socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket;

@property (/* atomic */ unsafe_unretained) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) dispatch_queue_t websocketQueue;

- (void)start;
- (void)stop;

- (void)sendMessage:(NSString *)msg;
- (void)sendData:(NSData *)msg;
- (void)didOpen;
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)msg;
- (void)didClose;
@end


@protocol WebSocketDelegate
@optional
- (void)webSocketDidOpen:(WebSocket *)ws;
- (void)webSocket:(WebSocket *)ws didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)msg;
- (void)webSocketDidClose:(WebSocket *)ws;
@end
```

and I have added above header file to XXXX-Bridging-Header.h like this

```
#import "WebSocket.h"
```

but when I want try to instantiate WebSocket class i can't see any initializer in autocompletion :
[image]

Comment: try to rename the class to something else, e.g. `MyWebSocket`. It could be a name collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are not importing the dependencies:

```
@class HTTPMessage;
@class GCDAsyncSocket;
```

are unknown to Swift because neither the bridging header or `WebSocket.h` is importing/including them. Therefore a method that uses them cannot be accessible in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(HTTPMessage *)request socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket;
```

with

```
- (id)initWithRequest:(HTTPMessage *)request socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: same as before . nothing changed :(